# An eigenvalue problem on a half circle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve the eigenvalue problem for the half-circle $x^2+y^2\le R^2$ $y\ge 0$ with homogeneous Dirichlet conditions as boundary conditions.

This is what I did:

Let $u=u(r,\phi)$

$$\Delta u=-\lambda u$$

$$R_{rr}\Phi+\frac{1}{r}R_r\Phi+\frac{1}{r^2}R\Phi_{\phi\phi}=-\lambda R\Phi$$

This gives $$\frac{r^2R_{rr}}{R}+\frac{rR_r}{R}+\frac{\Phi_{\phi\phi}}{\Phi}=-\lambda$$

Rearranging and setting both equations equal to some constant $\mu$:

$$\frac{r^2R_{rr}}{R}+\frac{rR_r}{R}+\lambda=-\frac{\Phi_{\phi\phi}}{\Phi}=\mu$$

Gives the two ODEs:

$$\frac{r^2R_{rr}}{R}+\frac{rR_r}{R}+\lambda=\mu$$
$$-\frac{\Phi_{\phi\phi}}{\Phi}=\mu$$

The second gives with Dirichlet conditions:

$$-\frac{\Phi_{\phi\phi}}{\Phi}=\mu \longrightarrow \Phi(\phi)=C_1\sin\sqrt{\mu}\phi$$

The former gives the Bessel equation,:

$$R_{rr}+rR_r+(\lambda-\mu)\frac{R}{r^2}=0 $$

But this should rather be in the form:

$$R_{rr}+rR_r+(\lambda-\frac{\mu}{r^2})R=0 $$

What went wrong, and what about the fact that with Dirichlet conditions we should also include $J(R)=0$? That gives a trivial solution.

Is this procedure incomplete?

Thanks

Comment: Dirichlet boundary condition imposed on where? The diameter plus the half-circle or just the diameter or just the half-circle?

Comment: General remark, you introduced the additional parameter $\mu$. The solution for the angular component depends on $\mu$. You should now also get a general solution for the radial component depending on both $\mu$ and $\lambda$. Then you plug in the boundary conditions and only for discrete values of $\lambda$ a finite number of non-trivial solutions (that is finitely many values of $\mu$) exist.

Comment: @CheeHan The entire boundary if you want a well-posed problem.

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...]
> $$R_{rr}\Phi+\frac{1}{r}R_r\Phi+\frac{1}{r^2}R\Phi_{\phi\phi}=-\lambda R\Phi$$
>
> This gives $$\frac{r^2R_{rr}}{R}+\frac{rR_r}{R}+\frac{\Phi_{\phi\phi}}{\Phi}=-\lambda$$
> [...]
>
> What went wrong[?]

A factor of $r^2$ has been dropped from the right-hand side at this step.

> But this should rather be in the form:
> $$R_{rr}+rR_r+(\lambda-\frac{\mu}{r^2})R=0 $$

The coefficient of the $R_r$ term here should be $1/r$.

> what about the fact that with Dirichlet conditions we should also include $J(R)=0$? That gives a trivial solution.

For the azimuthal equation, the zero-value condition at $\phi = \pi$ implies that $\sin (\sqrt{\mu} \pi) = 0$, and hence $\sqrt{\mu} = n$, where $n = 1, 2, 3, \text{etc}$.

Eventually you should get
$$R_{rr} + \frac{R_r}{r} + \left( \lambda-\frac{n^2}{r^2} \right) R = 0, $$
whose fundamental solutions are Bessel $J_n (r \sqrt{\lambda})$ and $Y_n (r \sqrt{\lambda})$.

- To get the solution to vanish at $r = 0$, you only want $J_n (r \sqrt{\lambda})$ (since Bessel-Y has a singularity).
- To get the solution to vanish at $r = r_\text{max}$ (I've avoided $R$ which clashes with the radial dependent variable), you need $r_\text{max} \sqrt{\lambda} = \alpha_{n,k}$, where $\alpha_{n,k}$ is the $k$th root of $J_n$, with $k = 1, 2, 3, \text{etc}$.

Comment: Thanks for this. So the solution is $$u(r,\theta)=J_n\bigg(\frac{\alpha_{n,k}}{J_n(R)}\bigg)\sin n\phi$$

Answer (score 2):

You forget to multiply $\lambda$ by $r^2$. It should be
$$ \frac{r^2R_{rr}}{R} + \frac{rR_r}{R} + \frac{\Phi_{\phi\phi}}{\Phi} = -\lambda r^2. $$
Following your notation, you would arrive at
$$ r^2R_{rr} + rR_r + (\lambda r^2 - \mu)R = 0. $$
This is a Bessel differential equation after you do a change of variable $s = \sqrt{\lambda} r$, which you can write down the solution.

Comment: Thanks Chee. What about the initial condition $J(R)=0$?

Comment: I added a comment above right after I realised your problem is on the upper half-disk. Where is the Dirichlet boundary condition being imposed? Is it on the half-circle only (without the diameter)?